# Maximum number of HTTP request in squid proxy server

Tags: http, squid

I have single Squid 3.4 instance running on Ubuntu Linux server. It is running in forward proxy mode and it is intercepting all HTTPS traffic.

I am currently load testing squid setup. My setup is as follows

1. Client: JMeter configured to make 1200 request at the same time. I am making '**HTTPS** PUT' call to store file in destination server.
2. Proxy: Squid is configured in forward proxy mode (SSL bump) which intercept all HTTPS traffic.
3. Destination server: It is well known storage provider and it is able to handle thousand of request at a time.

Without proxy, my JMeter is able execute all 1200 request successfully. But when I configured JMeter to pass through proxy I get '**Connection time out**' or '**socket write error**' error for around 3-4% of requests. **I want to find out why these requests are failing.**

I want to scale squid proxy server to handle as many requests as possible.

P.S.
Other similar questions '[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/169283/maximum-number-of-squid-proxy-connections)' and '[here](https://serverfault.com/questions/78588/maximum-number-of-connections-squid?rq=1)' doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: squid cannot intercept SSL unless you are using SSL bump.

Comment: Yes, it is running in SSL bump mode.